# Delete files with specific content

Tags: files, grep, delete, pattern-matching

Having a thousand of data files (same extension) in a directory, how to delete those which contain a specific parameter statement?

For example, if I wented to delete all files containing the line

```
Key = 0
```

could I do something like

```
grep -i "Key = 0" * | rm *
```

Comment: You mean the file would contain the literal string `Key = 0`?

Comment: The output of `grep` would include the filename and the line containing the string so instead of passing it to `rm`, it would just run the `rm` command on `*` which is everything in the directory and it would delete the files and give an error for directories because the `-r` switch isn't used. Do you want to delete the files that have that string in their contents? If so, provide an example of what it might look like. Do you also want to delete files that have `Key = 01` or `MyKey = 05`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command in the shell. This should do the job if pattern to be searched is `Key = 0`

```
grep -lrIZ "Key = 0" . | xargs -0 rm -f --
```

Generic command:

```
grep -lrIZ "<Pattern to be searched in the file>" . | xargs -0 rm -f --
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with the pipeline using `grep`+`rm` is that `rm` does not read from its standard input stream, which means that it does not read anything from the `grep` command on the left-hand side of the pipe.

Instead, the `rm *` on the right-hand side of the pipe would ignore all input and execute `rm` on every visible filename in the current directory.

Ignoring the issue with `rm` not reading its standard input, your `grep` command has two main issues:

1. It outputs matching lines with filenames.  This would be of no use to `rm` as we need to know *only* the filenames of the files we want to delete.
2. It matches `Key = 0` as a *substring*, which means it also matches `Crypto Key = 0x01` etc.

---

```bash
find . -type f -exec grep -q -F -x 'Key = 0' {} \; -exec rm -f {} +
```

or, with GNU `find` (and some others),

```bash
find . -type f -exec grep -q -F -x 'Key = 0' {} \; -delete
```

Both of these would look for regular files in the current directory or below, and for each found file, it would execute `grep -q -F -x 'Key = 0'`. This `grep` command would return an exit status signalling whether there is a line in the file that is *exactly* `Key = 0` (and nothing else).

The second `find` command will delete the file using its `-delete` predicate if such a line is found.  The first `find` command would collect the pathnames of the files containing this line and then run `rm -f` on batches of these.

The flags used with `grep` are

- `-q`, for quiet operation.  The utility does not output matching lines but exits successfully after the first match or with a non-zero exit status if the file does not contain a match.
- `-F`, for fixed string matching.  We are matching with a string, not a regular expression.
- `-x`, to find full-line matches only.  This has the same effect as if using a regular expression anchored to both the start and end of the line.

I'm not using `-i` with `grep` here as that would also delete files containing lines like `KEY = 0` and `kEY = 0` etc., and you have said nothing about these case variations.

Would you want the `find` command to be restricted to a particular filename suffix, like `.ext`, then use `-name '*.ext'` in the `find` command before the execution of `grep`.  For example:

```bash
find . -name '*.ext' -type f -exec grep -q -F -x 'Key = 0' {} \; -exec rm -f {} +
```